# how to convert table to one column (show ONLY what i mentioned in table shopping list)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have a table of shopping list that look like that example:

(a1) vegetables (b1) amount (c1) fruits (d1) amount (e1)drinks (f1) amount

and in row 2 and so on there is the list. so I want to see only the thing that I mark in one row.

Example: in the vegetables: 3 kg tomatoes, cucumber 0, 1 kg carrots.
so in the one column I see the title (vegetables) and 3 kg tomatoes and carrots 1 kg (without the cucumber) and so on...

you can do it by VBA or FORMULA and you can do it in another Sheet... whatever u want.

[image]

**as u can see, the Cucumber, Apple and Oranges NOT listed in the table on the right.**

Comment: please upload screenshot of your data as your problem isn't clear now.

Comment: Define a table and use filters.

Comment: uptade: upload a picture for example

Comment: Just use a pivot table or filter out blanks

Comment: @Raystafarian I'm afraid pivot table won't consolidate it to one column.

Comment: @MátéJuhász yeah, that's correct. I must have misunderstood the goal or the source, or both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *VBA* code should work:

```
Public Sub summary()
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws1 = wk.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ws1Columns = 1
    ws1Rows = 1
    maxColumns = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To maxColumns Step 2
        theRows = 1
        theCell = ws.Cells(theRows, i)
        theCell2 = ws.Cells(theRows, i + 1)
        While theCell <> ""
            If theCell2 <> "" Then
                ws1.Cells(ws1Rows, ws1Columns) = theCell
                ws1.Cells(ws1Rows, ws1Columns + 1) = theCell2
                ws.Cells(theRows, i).Copy
                ws1.Cells(ws1Rows, ws1Columns).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                ws.Cells(theRows, i + 1).Copy
                ws1.Cells(ws1Rows, ws1Columns + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                ws1Rows = ws1Rows + 1
            End If
            theRows = theRows + 1
            theCell = ws.Cells(theRows, i)
            theCell2 = ws.Cells(theRows, i + 1)
        Wend
    Next i
End Sub
```

Open VBA/Macros with ALT+F11, under *ThisWorkbook* add a new *module* and paste this code.

Execute the macro and if the original data is in `Sheet1` then the final result will be in `Sheet2`.

Comment: WOW thank you so much! It works great! you helped me alot. Now my job would be much more rapid and effective